Changing the background color of react-datepicker Calendar
I am using react-datepicker. Here, I have a calendar like this one:  
I have a class component and inside this class component, I have a method named renderDate() method. From the class components render method I am rendering the renderDate() method.
Here is the code snippet for that.
renderDate = () => {
        const { someData } = this.state;

        return (
            <span id="my-date-picker">
                <DatePicker
                    selected={someData}
                    onChange={this.myFunc}
                    showTimeSelect
                    className="form-control"
                    timeIntervals={15}
                    dateFormat={DATE_TIME_PICKER_FORMAT}
                />
            </span>
        );
  };

Now, As you can see in the picture, in the "Time" row of the calendar, I want it to be colored alternatingly. Odd rows are white (which is the default of the react-datepicker) and another row is #f0f0f0. For achieving this, I added a css like this:
#my-date-picker li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

By adding the CSS like above, the "time" row of the calendar now looks like this: 

Now, the problem is when I click on any time slot which is odd-numbered in the list then it is fine (like the picture 1, 2:30 PM is selected. And the background color changed to #216ba5 which is the default of react-datepicker). But, whenever I click any even-numbered time slot, it looks like the picture below 

Here, I selected the time slot of "9:15 AM". It is kind of invisible. I guess it is due to the CSS I added above, it is probably overwriting the default background color of the even-numbered time slot rows to #f0f0f0 where I was expecting for the selected time slots only be it even-numbered or not it should be the react-datetime default #216ba5. How can I achieve this and also retain the alternating color scheme that I have implemented for the "Time" column.

Hey Ryan, is there a live demo of the code where we can debug and post an answer for you?

unfortunately, no. it's a big project where I am working on my local computer.

You might want to try adding active psuedo class with same blue background for these event rows.

Based on  Sanket Sapate's answer, I tried to solve this problem by myself. 
I came out from the idea of using id css selector and I just get rid of it. Instead I used react-datepicker's built in class selector for that. I did this and it worked.
.react-datepicker__time-list-item:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

